# Parented higher hierarchy bones movements in pose mode disrupt lower hierarchy bones

Tags: rigging

My issue is that if I have a **line**

- X
- Y
- Z

with the letters as the **bone / joint**.

If I weight paint **X** - **Y** to move relative to **Z**, **X** relative to **Y** is left behind making the tube

- bend in a S shape instead of an **L** shape.

**How can I make X and Y move as one stick or unit instead of only moving Y and leaving X behind?**

[image]

Comment: Note: I did try weighting the vertex/modifying the bones. Auto-rigging did not work at all But was successful at linking the bone to mesh.

Comment: could you please show some screenshots, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hope this link works: https://imgur.com/vF4t7qB  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The file Size was too large to upload. Still I tried alternate weight painting solid or in gradient. If I painted only over the bone the above happened. If I painted all the bones down from the respective bone, the above photo was my result. If I normalize all the above happened. If I gradient paint, the program acts as if the different weights are the same and the above happens. Binding the bones with automatic weights CTRL+P after selection did not do anything for weights. It only bound the bones to the mesh for me to weight paint them.

Comment: I tried to remake a mesh totally from scratch. I tried alternate weight paints many youtube tutorials and also tried to add/remove modifiers/align vertex/ normalize all.  This problem has been repeating itself though. I am trying to re-download blender after copying some youtube videos and getting different results.